# Background image for animated SVG Path element

Tags: javascript, svg

Hello I came across a really interesting looking website :

http://digitalbakery.org/

I wonder how did they provide a background image for the animated SVG Path elements?

I have tried to set a background image for SVG before. Did not work. However looking in the DOM I see in fact the images and SVG are entirely separated. The `img` are in a `ul` element specified somewhere.

Is the `Path` element, when `hover`, has its opacity reduced to zero hence revealing the img underneath? If so I cannot seem to figure out how is the exact location worked out. How can this effect be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the named clipPath to crop images. The simplest example:

```
<svg id="pLayout">
    <g>
        <clipPath id="hex-mask">
            <path d="..."></path>
        </clipPath>
    </g>
    <image x="..." y="..." xlink:href="..." **clip-path="url(#hex-mask)"** />
</svg>
```

Location calculates by container's vertexes.